# Adding Checkbutton Options from database with Tkinter Menubutton

Tags: python, tkinter

I have categories saved in a database on table Geo_Cat. I know my geo_list is getting populated correctly, because I was able to make an OptionMenu earlier. I also printed the list and it worked. So the query is good. However, I need to be able to select more than one option at a time and need to use a MenuButton instead. The options that I need are none and the categories in the table. I've been able to add the "None" checkbutton, but I haven't been able to add the geo_list. Below is a code excerpt:

```
from Tkinter import *


root = Tk()

location_frame = Frame(root)
location_frame.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
location_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
location_frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
location_frame.pack(pady=25, padx=50)

geo_list= ["geo1","geo2","geo3","geo4"]

amb = Menubutton(location_frame,text="Geo Category", relief=RAISED)
amb.grid(sticky="ew", row=1,column=0)
amb.menu = Menu(amb,tearoff=0)
amb['menu'] = amb.menu 
Item0 = IntVar()
amb.menu.add_checkbutton(label="None", variable=Item0)
location_vars = {}
for category in geo_list:
    location_vars["Item{0}".format(category)] = IntVar()
    amb.menu.add_checkbutton(label=geo_list[category])
amb.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

I also tried this:

```
location_vars["Item{0}".format(category)] = IntVar()
amb.menu.add_checkbutton(label=geo_list[category], 
variable=location_vars["Item{0}".format(category)])
```

[image]

How can I add my geo_list to the checkbuttons? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your code does not run. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Got it. I modified the code.Thanks!

Comment: The code gives an error which seems pretty self-explanatory. What are you expecting `geo_list[category]` to return?

Comment: My apologies. I'm a new developer and I'm not sure what the error message means and how to fix it. I've been working on this all day. I want for geo1, geo2, geo3, geo4 from geo_list to be added to the checkbutton list and then appear in the window.

Comment: Read about [Common Sequence Operations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#index-22) and 
[how to use lists in Python](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/lists/python-lists-cheat-sheet)

Comment: I thought I could turn the list into integers with this: 
    location_vars["Item{0}".format(category)] = IntVar()
I can't find the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the items in the `geo_list` for menu labels, why not just set them; you are already looping over them:

```
amb.menu.add_checkbutton(label=category)
```

Also, don't pack amb at the very end; you have already gridded it earlier.

I'm adding an example of how to trace changes associated with each menu item. I have changed the code slightly but I think you will have no problem to get the general idea.

I'm using a `BooleanVar()` instead of an `IntVar()`, then each var is saved in `location_vars` with the key `"Item{0}".format(category)`. Finally I'm setting up a trace for changes in each menu item to to a callback function which will inspect the selections.

Is this what you are after?

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

amb = Menubutton(root, text="Geo Category", relief=RAISED)
amb.pack(padx=50, pady=25)
amb.menu = Menu(amb, tearoff=0)
amb['menu'] = amb.menu

def callback(*args):
    # Callvack function is called when menu items are changed
    for key, value in location_vars.items():
        print(key, value.get())
    print() # To make the printout more readable

geo_list= ["None","geo1","geo2","geo3","geo4"]
location_vars = {}
for category in geo_list:
    location_vars["Item{0}".format(category)] = BooleanVar()
    # Set "variable" for every menu item
    amb.menu.add_checkbutton(label=category,
        variable=location_vars["Item{0}".format(category)])
    # Trace changes in the variables
    location_vars["Item{0}".format(category)].trace("w", callback)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: figbeam,  thank you for taking the time to reply. That works great for displaying the list on the menu. My new problem is that the list actually originates from a database. I need it to display the name but save it's id.Would correcting the code below not accomplish that goal? 
    location_vars["Item{0}".format(category)] = IntVar()
    amb.menu.add_checkbutton(label=geo_list[category])

Comment: That worked wonderfully. Thank you for adding the comments. It helped me learn. Thanks for everything!